# How to move “answers” rows into under column “questions”?

Tags: formulas, microsoft-excel

In Excel, how do I move answers from other column to same question under another column, can any one guide the exact formula to achieve this? See example below what needs to be achieved as shown in picture.

[image: Excel to move column]

Comment: Welcome. This site is about web applications. The answer will be about Google Sheets. Not Excel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as is defined in [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following **[`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)** formula

```
=FLATTEN(A2:C4)
```

[image]

### OR

```
={"Questions";FLATTEN(A2:C4)}
```

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.